# How can I set the date format to a custom one?

Tags: forms, 8, datetime

The default date format used by Drupal 8 is *d.m.Y*. I want to change it to *d-M-Y*.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't change the date format.

```php
$form['start_date'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start date'),
  '#format' => 'd-m-Y',
];
```

Even when I replaced `#format` with `#date_format`, the date was still using the default format.

What is the correct property to use for the date format, if `#format` and `#date_format` aren't recognized?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Drupal 8, the properties for the date format and the time format are two different and separated properties: `#date_date_format` sets the date format, while `#date_time_format` sets the time format, as in the following code.

```php
$date_format = 'Y-m-d';
$time_format = 'H:i';
    
$form['start_date'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start date'),
  '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
  '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
];
```

Unfortunately, when HTML5 form elements are used for a *datetime* form element, the date and time formats must be one of the HTML5 formats. This is described in the documentation for [`Datetime::processDatetime()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/function/Datetime%3A%3AprocessDatetime/8.9.x), which contains the following text.

> **#date_date_format**: A date format string that describes the format that should be displayed to the end user for the date. When using HTML5 elements the format MUST use the appropriate HTML5 format for that element, no other format will work. See the [`DateFormatterInterface::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatterInterface.php/function/DateFormatterInterface%3A%3Aformat/8.9.x) function for a list of the possible formats and HTML5 standards for the HTML5 requirements. Defaults to the right HTML5 format for the chosen element if a HTML5 element is used, otherwise defaults to [`DateFormat::load('html_date')->getPattern()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Entity%21DateFormat.php/function/DateFormat%3A%3AgetPattern/8.9.x).

> **#date_time_format**: A date format string that describes the format that should be displayed to the end user for the time. When using HTML5 elements the format MUST use the appropriate HTML5 format for that element, no other format will work. See the `DateFormatterInterface::format()` function for a list of the possible formats and HTML5 standards for the HTML5 requirements. Defaults to the right HTML5 format for the chosen element if a HTML5 element is used, otherwise defaults to `DateFormat::load('html_time')->getPattern()`.

As [Christian](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/292/christian) pointed out in [his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211064/how-can-i-set-the-date-format-to-a-custom-one#comment307392_211074), there is an issue that (as of today, December 3, 2021) is currently open: [Datetime element formats are confusing](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2875131).

Comment: Further reading on this. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2875131. Note 'DateTime supports only "Y-m-d".'