# Set date format in Firefox

Tags: forms, 8

I read a recent [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211064/how-to-set-date-format-in-drupal-8-for-date-time-field/211074#211074) about using date formats in forms, and using the code works OK in Google Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari it is not working.

The default date is shown like YYYY-mm-dd, while the datepicker renders a dd-mm-YYYY field. After submitting, I get an error about the date format.
When I use `$form_element['#date_date_element'] = 'text'`, it works OK, but I do not get a datepicker.

Comment: I'll look at this tonight, but I think may be a bug with the implementation of he datepicker polyfill, https://www.drupal.org/node/1835016